# Add new distribution to JAGS or OpenBUGS?

Tags: jags

I would like model some variables using a distribution that is not neither JAGS' nor OpenBUGS core distributions. Do you know how can I implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ['zeros trick'](http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manuals/Tricks.html#SpecifyingANewSamplingDistribution).